# Как отключить всплывающее окно, если пользователь авторизирован

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как отключить всплывающее окно, если пользователь авторизирован.
Плагин Popup Maker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию `is_user_logged_in`:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Ваш код для popup'а
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/